# PostgreSQL insert x times 2 same rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, multidimensional-array, sql-insert

I have the following table:

```
          user_setting
----+---------+--------------+---------------
 id | user_id | setting_name | setting_value
----+---------+--------------+---------------
  1 |    1    |     color    |     000000
  2 |    1    |     date     |     aammjj
  3 |    2    |     color    |     000000
  4 |    2    |     date     |     aammjj
  5 |    3    |     color    |     000000
  6 |    3    |     date     |     aammjj
```

Have you got a solution to fill the table with these values in 3 `INSERT` and an array that contains the `setting_name` and associate default `setting_value`?
I was thinking about:

```
INSERT INTO user_setting (user_id, setting_name, setting_value)
            ( SELECT 1, params[1], params[2]
              FROM unnest(ARRAY[['color','000000'],['date','aammjj']]) AS params )
INSERT INTO user_setting (user_id, setting_name, setting_value)
            ( SELECT 1, params[1], params[2]
              FROM unnest(ARRAY[['color','000000'],['date','aammjj']]) AS params )
INSERT INTO user_setting (user_id, setting_name, setting_value)
            ( SELECT 3, params[1], params[2]
              FROM unnest(ARRAY[['color','000000'],['date','aammjj']]) AS params )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_id, p1, p2
from
    (values (1),(2),(3)) u (user_id)
    cross join
    (values ('color','000000'),('date','aammjj')) as params (p1, p2)
;
 user_id |  p1   |   p2   
---------+-------+--------
       1 | color | 000000
       1 | date  | aammjj
       2 | color | 000000
       2 | date  | aammjj
       3 | color | 000000
       3 | date  | aammjj
```